# How to get the number of GPU cores using CLI

Tags: command-line

Is there a way to get the number of GPU cores on an Intel Mac?

On a M1

`ioreg -l | grep num_cores`

will display the number of GPU cores, but on my iMac 5K 2017 with an AMD GPU it does not.

The same counts for

`system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType`

which does the job on M1 but not on my Intel machine.

Comment: This post does not say that they want to use that value in a script. I submitted a way to tell how many cores there are by using htop, and it was down-voted!

Answer (score 1):

All I've got that might help is using `ioreg -l | grep model` to help grab the model of device + model of the GPU.

The number of core units could be somewhere within `ioreg -l | grep IOKitDiagnostics` but I was happy just finding the GPU model.