# GPU-specific stats/view on Apple Silicon

Tags: mac, gpu, apple-silicon, activity-monitor

On Apple silicon Macs, how can stats like frequency and utilization particular to GPUs be observed?

Activity Monitor gives a nice graph on Activity Monitor's CPU History screen.
Activity Monitor's Window -> GPU History screen shows an amalgamated view, not particular to GPUs.

[asitop](https://github.com/tlkh/asitop) gives visuals using the [powermetrics](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/powermetrics/) utility. The screenshot for asitop shows just "GPU" for usage and power.

Is this possible, to view GPU-specific stats?

Also, would there be some way to check the health of the GPU cores? Could it be possible that one or some of them have become defective but the system still functions? Maybe this paragraph would be a separate question, but I think this is the root concern I have in asking the first question.

Comment: Do you have some reason for thinking that your GPU might be defective? What problem have you observed? I would only consider a defective GPU when you have ruled out several other possibilities.

Comment: Mainly, at this point, I'd like to be able to confirm the GPU count on the machines. I'd also like to be able to check GPU utilization for patterns, to verify they're working. Would you know?

Comment: Run a GPU benchmark and see if it's comparable with known results for that model. Again, what makes you think there might be a problem?

Comment: Like I said, I'm looking to verify the functional GPU count - regardless of any problem. Would any benchmark util show results per GPU?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438289/how-to-get-the-number-of-gpu-cores-using-cli